# Problem when returning struct within the class

Tags: c++

I am having a problem when trying to return my struct in C ++ I am still new to that language.

I have the following code

Header File

```
class Rec : public Rect {
public:
    Rec();

    struct xRect
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    struct SRect
    {
        int position;
        xRect *mtype;
        int value;
        bool enable;
    };

    struct xRect ReturnXRect();

};
```

Cpp file

```
struct xRect Rec::ReturnXRect() {

    struct SRect *xrec = xRe::sRect();

    if (xrec)
        return xrec->mtype;

    return nullptr;
}
```

I am getting error C2556 and C2371. someone what correct way to work struct in the class?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using pointers in the CPP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the name of the class to `xRect`. like this:

```
//---Header file

class Rec : public Rect {
public:
    Rec();

    struct xRect
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    struct SRect
    {
        int position;
        xRect *mtype;
        int value;
        bool enable;
    };

    xRect ReturnXRect();   //note: you don't to add the struct keyword

};
```

---

```
//---Cpp file

Rec::xRect Rec::ReturnXRect() {
//^------------------------------------added Rec:: on return type. `struct`
                                        // keyword is unnecessary.

    SRect *pRec = new SRect();  //i'm assuming this is just an example way 
                                //   to creating your SRect object in your 
                                //   example code. you don't need to allocate 
                                //   actually.

    xRect retVal;

    if (pRec){
        retVal = pRec->mtype;
        delete pRec;             //destroy to avoid memory leak.
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

since `xRect` is defined outside of the scope of the class(unless it's inside `ReturnXRect()` you need to add the `Rec::` to inform the compiler what version of `xRect` you meant to use. since there might be other `xRect` version of struct defined outside probably from header files.

I also fixed content of `ReturnXRect()` function so it won't have syntax errors.

Comment: is now pointing out another error C2440 pointing to `xrec->` and `nullptr`

Comment: @carolzinha, i didn't notice the content of the function i just copy-pasted it. ;)) thanks for noticing.